# Can iframes be turned on/off on the server-side?

Tags: javascript, iframe, apache

Can iframes be turned on/off on the server-side?

Shouldn't `<iframe/>` support be client-side? Is it possible that GoDaddy has `<iframe/>`s disabled by default? Is this even something that can be controlled server-side? This is just a standard Apache `httpd` server with no bells/whistles (no app servers, proxies, etc.). Is there some kind of server-side JavaScript that GoDaddy could be executing "around" my pages that prevents `<iframe/>`s from being used? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe a good response on that email is:'Sure, done!' and then wait for the drama to evolve? Let us know what happens...

Comment: The [`X-Frames-Option`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header) header can be used to ask a browser to not display a page in a frame.

Comment: Pointy & rene - these are interesting comments, but do not help answer my question. @RobW - can you elaborate? Is this `X-Frames-Option` sent back in the HttpResponse? If so, is GoDaddy putting a proxy in between the client-side and the pages and preventing them from sending back iframes? If not, can you explain what this header is? Thanks again, and +1!

Comment: I see your question more as a joke :) thanks for sharing though! And Rob new thing learnt thanks for sharing ! Will explore

Comment: The point is that the designer is either incompetent or the question was garbled.  It doesn't make any sense as you've presented it. Yes there are headers and stuff but that's not about allowing or disallowing `<iframe>` elements in your pages, but about control over whether a site should be rendered in an `<iframe>`.

Comment: All - please see my edit above.

Comment: The answer is via Rob W... the web SERVER can request that browsers not allow resources to be in frames.  It's a security measure.

Comment: An example: main.html: `<iframe src="sub.html"></iframe>`. When the server which server sub.html includes the X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN header in the response, browsers which understand this header will not load the resource in the frame. (the spelling of the header is `X-Frame-Options`, by the way, I accidentally placed the `s` at the wrong place in my previous comment). The server of `main.html` cannot force the client to not display any frames though.

Comment: It's a request from the server to tell the browser not show something in an IFRAME.  Each browser can implement what to do with the request.  An example might be badsite.html having an IFRAME with bank.html in it, then trying to do bad things with it.  The server hosting bank.html can request that bank.html not be allowed in IFRAMES.  Good browsers won't allow it.

Comment: @mark (+1) again! Thanks for explaining things in simple terms that make sense. So can you confirm that if `bank.html` has `X-Frame-Options` set to `"DENY`, then when `badsite.html` tries to include `bank.html` inside an `<iframe/>`, the browser won't render the iframe? Can you also confirm that when `X-Frame-Options` is set to `SAMEORIGIN` that the opposite occurs? Also, what's the default (what if the header isn't specified at all)? Thanks again, and if you put all this into an answer, I'll happily give you the green check!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A web SERVER can request via a HTTP header in a response that browsers not allow resources to be in frames.  It's a security measure.

Browser request to server:

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.bank.com
```

Server response to browser:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: ...
```

Each browser can implement what to do with that request.  An example might be badsite.html having an IFRAME with bank.html in it, then trying to do bad things with it. The server hosting bank.html can request that bank.html not be allowed in a frame (via "DENY"). A "good" browser will recognize the request and not allow bank.html in a frame.  If for some reason bank.html should be in a frame, but only in one from THEIR OWN site, they could use the "SAMEORIGIN" option, which would work on their site but not on anyone else's site.  Default is to allow frames in general.

Comment: Mark, could you please rephrase your answer so that it contains relevant details/links? Not everyone is going to read the answers at the question (also, paragraphs don't hurt ;))

Comment: yeah my text was kind-of just running along there... trying to help where possible whilst working... i'll do a quick edit